# Angjularjs Adding Controller to index.html gives blank page

Tags: angularjs, controller

Brand new to Angular.  I have a controller that when I add it to my list of script files on in index.html page, my site stops working and I get blank pages for all of my views.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?  I'm adding the controller to my index.html file like this

```
<script src="app/components/common/ModalDemoCtrl.js"></script>
```

And I'll paste my controller code below if that's part of the problem.

```
var app = angular.module('crm.ma', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};

$scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
};

});


app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

$scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
};

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
});
```

If anyone could help me that'd be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what errors are thrown? What is `$uibModal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service `$uibModal` has been introduced very lately, in version 0.14.0 of `ui-bootstrap`. I guess you are still on a version < 0.14.0 of `ui-bootstrap`, therefore, replace:

```
$uibModal
```

with

```
$modal
```

Or update `ui-bootstrap` to 0.14+